# I have developed a WordPress website using localhost.How can I give that to my client?

Tags: wordpress

I have developed a WordPress website using localhost. Now I am giving that site to my client. What files do I need to give him and how will I generate those files?

Comment: From the tag description: _Questions about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, and server configuration are off-topic here_ So, you might get help on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: just use google search for that purpose. there are thousands posts about migrating Wordpress website. Also, there are hundreds plugins for reach your goal

Comment: can I do it without plugins ? just by moving .sql file and wordpress folder?

Comment: Yes you can five entire wordpress folder and .sql file. But client should change the `home_url` and `site_url` and also URLS from post by using plugin like `Better Search and Replace`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand as the question could hit a few different scenarios. 
I'm assuming for localhost you mean you've developed the application locally, therefore you could move your local application to the live site - for a simple guide on how to do this check out: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

The idea of local development is that the application is built *locally* on your machine, for this to be available to everyone, the project needs to be deployed to live (i.e the files transferred to a live site). 
You could then provide your client with the domain address or hand over the account completely - I suppose that process is up to you.

It's probably a good idea if you are interested to have a read through the different types of environments developers use for their projects - development, testing, staging, production. To read more have a look here: https://codewithintent.com/different-types-of-development-environments/

I hope this helps!

Comment: look , I have developed a website for a client , he will host that , I am a beginner and totally clueless that what should I  give to him , Is giving .sql file And word press folder enough ?

Answer (score 0):

I am working with wordpress for a quite long & i have also came across the same situation where we develop the site on other domain & then we need to deploy it to client site. The best way is to simply install this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

After installing go to the plugin options & export the website It will gave you one file.

Then at the client side install a fresh copy of wordpress install the same plugin again & then go to plugin settings & import the file here. It will take some time after doing it just refresh the page & you will be good to go.